# plist and status - "127 The specified service did not ship with the operating system"

Tags: mac, launchctl, plist

I'm trying to get a script to run via launchd, but I keep getting a status of 127 after I load it.  I've checked ownership, permissions and absolute paths etc of both plist and script.  I'm running it on a mac with macos 10.13.
Here's the plist:

```
<dict>

    <key>Label</key>

    <string>com.parkridge.UrlHistory</string>

    <key>StartInterval</key>

    <integer>21600</integer>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>

    <array>

        <string>/bin/sh</string>

        <string>/Users/Shared/Resources/Logs.sh</string>

    </array>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>

    <true/>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>

    <string>/dev/null</string>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>

    <string>/dev/null</string>

</dict>
```

I can also run the script manually and it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, 127 can mean a host of different things, but it often comes down to paths and permissions. What are the permissions and the ownership of Logs.sh?

Comment: Thanks MMB, The permissions are set to 644 and ownership root:wheel.

Comment: That's correct. Next thing I'd check is your Logs.sh script. The path launchd gets is different from what you get. When in doubt, hardcode all paths to any executables you call within the script.

Comment: MMB, I went back and hard coded the paths... that seems to have fix it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 127 can mean a host of different things, but it often comes down to paths and permissions. The script should be owned by root:wheel and set to 644.

As for paths, launchd has PATH settings different than you, so the simplest solution is to hardcode all the paths to executables within your script.